# Is there a way to use a for-each construction for a Guava Table?

Tags: java, foreach, guava

One of the cleanest coding benefits of the modern Collections is the ability to use the for-each construction. I have below a simple general table printing method, followed by a test loading method. While this works, some kind of for-each would be a lot cleaner. Any ideas?

```
public void printTable(Table table)
{
    int numRows = table.rowKeySet().size();
    int numCols = table.columnKeySet().size();

    for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++) 
    {
           for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++) 
           {
               System.out.print( table.get(i,j) + " " );
           }
           System.out.println();
    }
}          
Table<Integer, Integer, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
void makeTable()
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
           for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
               table.put(i, j, i*j+2);
}
```

Comment: foreach loops only work with arrays and things that implement `Iterable`.  Guava's `Table` is neither of those, so you're stuck with your indexed for loop.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, but is a bit disappointing. Thanks!

Comment: The above construction, and similar ones using row and column keys forced me to check for null entries in a complex table in which things were added and removed. The following approach works much better:Collection <Coral> coral = table.values(); for(Coral coral:corals) { System.out.println( coral ); }

Comment: What's the lineage of Coral and Collection in your above method?  java.util.Collection or the guava Collection2 object?  Coral is found where?  Cheers!

Comment: Coral is the class I made which I am keeping track of in the table -- as opposed to the simple number example I used in the illustration. They simulate actual corals in nature that are recruited and die, with rows representing species. Collection is just the java.util.Collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just call `Map<R,Map<C,V>> rowMap()` and iterate over it?

Also, I think you might prefer a `TreeBasedTable` which accounts for row and column order, since you are using integers for the rows and columns and it seems you want to iterate on the natural order of those.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out the Map approach. This is a test example for constructions I will use with objects (corals) in a reef modelling system. Each row is a coral species. I will be shuffling objects within the rows before stepping through them, and so not really after a natural ordering.

Comment: Yep, this is the preferred way to do it.  Iterate over the `entrySet()`s of the `Map`s.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have been doing that with simple HashMaps, and will it try on the table.